# What causes a particular object to have a tendency to go outwards in circular motion when the centripetal force is inwards to the center

Tags: friction, inertial-frames, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force, inertia

Like a circular bead with a thread passing through it and the system being rotated . It can't be centrifugal force as it is pseudo only and has no existence when we are already in an inertial frame like an stationary person outside the assembly. Help in clearing the doubt taking all cases in account :- Uniform and Non Uniform motion, presence and absence of friction between the thread and bead.

Answer (score 2):

The object isn't being forced to outwards: it is trying to go in a straight line. If there is insufficient force to keep it in a circular orbit, it will follow a path that is "more straight". From the rotating frame of reference, that looks like it is "not moving". From the "outside" reference, the object is going straight.

Comment: Is this the case of uniform circular motion that it will continue to go out due to insufficient force not changing its magnitude. Will then in case of non uniform motion , as the velocity of object will increase the centripetal force will increase and then the body may start slowly turn its motion from spiral outwards to spiral inwards ?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two points. One is that of fictitious forces ad addressed in the previous answer. The other is the moon slowly increasing its orbit due to earth - moon tidal interection. I am confident it has been already discussed here and in astronomy. I really wanted to point that you somehow mixed these two aspects and the answer addressed only one, but I can't comment. If someone could FLAG me, perhaps the moderators could made a brief comment and delete this answer from me.